# Trying to remember book about virtual reality

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

The story is about a man who slowly but gradually finds out that he is living in a virtual reality. Eventually they let him return to the real reality, but then, after a while he starts to notice things again that make him suspect that once more he's in a virtual reality.

It's a bit similar to what the Enterprise (TNG) crew did with holodeck character Moriarty, but that's not the story I mean. Also, if I remember correctly, the equipment is a bit similar to that in The Matrix.

I remember reading this story when on holiday in 1996 and the book was probably quite recent then. The copy I read was in English and I'm pretty sure the author is American.

Comment: It was written in English (American) and I'm quite sure the author is American.

Comment: Kudos to LSemi! I think you hit the nail on the head!

Comment: Did you ever verify LSemi's answer? If so, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

This *might* be *Realtime Interrupt* by J. P. Hogan, published in 1995.

https://sfbook.com/realtime-interrupt.htm

> As a brilliant scientist at a leading computer corporation, Joe
>   Corrigan heads an ambitious project, dubbed Oz, to create a virtual
>   reality system capable of mimicking reality in every detail. When he
>   later awakens in a psychiatric ward with much of his memory gone and
>   Oz apparently terminated, his predominant concern is to find a new
>   place for himself in a world that now seems strangely mundane and
>   humorless. Then into his life walks Lilly, who has a recent personal
>   history uncannily like his, and Joe begins to catch on: Oz was never
>   terminated, and he and Lilly are trapped in a computer simulation
>   being run for a purpose Joe never approved ([source](https://www.buffalolib.org/vufind/Record/841549/Reviews))

Not so good a match, *Death Dream* by Ben Bova, published 1994 ( https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/302511.Death_Dream ).

Comment: @LSemi. +1.  This was my first thought as well.

Comment: I think LSemi is correct! Many thanks!

Comment: If it turns out to be it (you can get the ebook from Baen.com) you can mark the answer as correct.